# CENTOS 8 - cannot bind to UDP port from service

Tags: centos, centos8

I did a fresh install of powerdns on CentOS 8 Desktop. When running the service on port 53 everything runs without issue. When changing the port 5300 it errors out. I receive this error message:

```
visitel-vpn1.localdomain systemd[1]: Started PowerDNS Authoritative Server.
Loading '/usr/lib64/pdns/libgmysqlbackend.so'
This is a standalone pdns
Listening on controlsocket in '/var/run/pdns/pdns.controlsocket'
Unable to bind UDP socket to '0.0.0.0:5300': Permission denied
Fatal error: Unable to bind to UDP socket
```

here is my service file. I stripped down the service file to bare minimum and added the --local-port to the command line parameter.

```
[Unit]
Description=PowerDNS Authoritative Server

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pdns_server --guardian=no --daemon=no --disable-syslog --log-timestamp=no --write-pid=no --local-port=5300
User=root
Group=root
RuntimeDirectory=pdns

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Things I have tried:

- running PowerDNS with default settings default port. WORKS
- running as root in the console with port 5300. WORKS
- PowerDNS on Ubuntu 20 Server running as service on port 5300. WORKS
- disabled firewalld. FAIL
- running powerDNS service with port 0.0.0.0:5300 or 127.0.0.0:5300 or [localip]:5300. FAIL
- running PowerDNS on any port other than 53 such as 25, 1000, 1024, 54. FAIL

There is some security setting in CentOS 8 Desktop that is restricting services from binding to UDP ports. I can just run Ubuntu but I would like to know why it's failing on CentOS. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: My recommendation would be to look at SELinux. In my experience with RHEL-based systems port-based problems are almost always caused by either Firewalld (which you've already disabled) or SELinux. To test whether selinux is the problem run `sudo setenforce 0` to disable it temporarily. 

Note, **[do not permanently disable selinux](https://stopdisablingselinux.com/)**. If disabling it using `setenforce 0` (and restarting the service) works then look into the selinux logs to see what you need to do to grant the service permission to use that port.

Comment: make sure selinux is not blocking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux only allows the DNS server to bind to ports labeled as `dns_port_t`, which currently are:

```
# semanage port -l | grep -w 53
dns_port_t                     tcp      53, 853
dns_port_t                     udp      53, 853
```

You can add your own custom port to allow this access.

```
# semanage port -a -t dns_port_t -p udp 5300
# semanage port -l | grep -w 53
dns_port_t                     tcp      53, 853
dns_port_t                     udp      5300, 53, 853
```

(You probably also need to allow TCP, and configure it in PowerDNS.)

Comment: I added both udp and tcp ports 5300. it works. I didn't know about SELinux I'll have to read up on it. Thank you.